# Rails 3 passing parameter to new method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Okay, am going nuts trying to get this to work. I want to pass information I need to the new action and it ain't working. I am in a view and using **link_to** with a path to create a new record:

```
<%= link_to "New", new_libation_path(:xid=> 123) %>
```

My routes table has:  **resources :libations**

And in the libation_controller I have my new action...

```
def new
  puts params[:xid]    #This is nil!
  ...
```

What am I doing wrong? Maybe I should google how to use params in rails..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This looks right. Is the query string in the URL showing up as it should? Check on your rails console that `app.new_libation_path(:xid => 123)` is returning the correct URL, and that this URL is showing up in your HTML markup:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > app.new_user_path(:test => 'test')
 => "/users/new?test=test"
```

(from an app I had handy)

Comment: Aaaargh! Thanks for the tip of using console. Of course it worked. It quickly pointed me to the fact that I had been modifying the **wrong** (but similar) view file!!! I shall now go and get spankings...

Comment: Haha, it happens to us all! Glad to help. Now [go buy a rubber duck](http://compsci.ca/blog/rubber-ducks-help-best-with-computer-science/).